# Does alcohol raise ketone levels in healthy subjects?

Tags: alcohol, ketone

In a healthy person, does consumption of alcohol raise ketone levels? And if so, is there a positive correlation between amount consumed and ketone levels?

My findings so far include [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2564331/) from the National Library of Medicine on Alcoholic Ketoacidosis, but I get the impression from this article that this relates to alcohol dependent subjects. My question is just about affects of alcohol on healthy subjects in relation to ketone increase. Thanks.